# NullPointerException при работе с TableView

Tags: java, javafx

Не могу понять в чем проблема, вроде все делаю по oracle tutorials. Но что-то не все верно получается.

`Main.java`

```
package sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        Parent parentRoot = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("../fxml/parentRoot.fxml"));
        Parent centerRoot = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("../fxml/centerRoot.fxml"));
        BorderPane borderPane = (BorderPane) parentRoot;
        AnchorPane anchorPane = (AnchorPane) centerRoot;
        borderPane.setCenter(anchorPane);
        Scene loadScene = new Scene(borderPane);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Service");
        primaryStage.setScene(loadScene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

`primaryController.java`

```
package controllers;

import classes.Person;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;

public class primaryController {

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Person, String> firstNameColumn;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Person, String> lastNameColumn;
    @FXML
    private Label firstNameLabel;
    @FXML
    private Label lastNameLabel;
    @FXML
    private TableView<Person> personTable;

    private ObservableList<Person> personData = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    @FXML
    private void initialize() {
        personData.add(new Person("Denys", "Savenko"));
        personData.add(new Person("Evgeniy", "Revutskiu"));

        firstNameColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("firstName"));
        lastNameColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("lastName"));
        personTable.setItems(personData);
    }
}
```

`Person.java`

```
package classes;

import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;

public class Person {

    private SimpleStringProperty firstName;
    private SimpleStringProperty lastName;

    public Person(String firstName, String lastName) {
        this.firstName = new SimpleStringProperty(firstName);
        this.lastName  = new SimpleStringProperty(lastName);
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName.set(firstName);
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return this.firstName.get();
    }

    public SimpleStringProperty firstNameProperty() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = new SimpleStringProperty(lastName);
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return this.lastName.get();
    }

    public SimpleStringProperty lastNameProperty() {
        return lastName;
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Файлы parentRoot.fxml и centerRoot.fxml не привожу (думаю там ничего интересного нету). Stack trace, который я получаю в итоге:

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$155(LauncherImpl.java:182)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/E:/IntelliJ%20IDEA%20Projects/Service/out/production/Service/fxml/parentRoot.fxml

    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2601)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2571)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2441)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3214)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3175)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3148)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3124)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3104)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3097)
    at sample.Main.start(Main.java:15)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$162(LauncherImpl.java:863)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$175(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2566)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at controllers.primaryController.initialize(primaryController.java:32)
    ... 27 more
Exception running application sample.Main

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Скорее всего у Вас не находятся файлы `*.fxml`. Посмотрите что у Вас содержится в переменных `parentRoot` и `centerRoot`. Файлы `*.fxml` должны находиться в папке `resources` и тогда доступ к ним пожно будет получить `getClass().getResource("/fxml/parentRoot.fxml")`

Comment: @Bleser а почему файлы должны находиться в папке `resources`? Раньше был похожий проект с подобной структурой, все работало.

Comment: Просто при сборке в jar файл, придется постоянно следить за тем что бы рядом с ним находились файлы fxml, а если поместить их внутрь jar'ника об этом можно не беспокоится. Если Вам нужно что бы файлы загружались по относительному пути нужно использовать не `getClass().getResource()`, а `File`

Comment: У Вас даже в логе видно что JavaFX не может загрузить fxml файл.
`Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/E:/IntelliJ%20IDEA%20Projects/Service/out/production/Service/fxml/parentRoot.fxml`

Comment: @Bleser как узнать откудого начинается путь `getClass().getResource()`? Чтобы верно его указать.

Comment: Для `getClass().getResource()` путь начинается из каталога `resources`. Допустим файл `file.txt` находится по такому пути `C:\...\src\main\resource\1.txt`, то путь нужно указать `/1.txt`

Comment: @Bleser все равно ошибка, по прежнему не загружает parentRoot. Я добавил картинку в вопрос со структурой проекта.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68253/discussion-between-bleser-and-not-a-programmer).

Comment: Какой системой сборки пользуетесь?

Comment: стандартной, среда IntellijIDEA

Answer (score 0):

Поскольку вы не используете систему сборки, IDEA сама не понимает, что в папке resources находятся ресурсы. На скриншоте видно, что эта директория обозначена как обычная. Папка с ресурсами помечается другим значком, несколько отличающимся от стандартного: [image: значок директории resources]

В вашем случае должно быть достаточно прописать полный путь до файлов fxml, считая за корень папку src, т.е.:

```
Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/resources/parentRoot.fxml"));
Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/resources/centerRoot.fxml"));
```

Comment: та же ошибка :(